# search vb.net form using sqldatasource

Tags: search

This is my first time creating a search form. I am trying to create a form currently with two fields to enter last and first name. When the button is clicked I would like to get results from the table. Sounds simple. I browsed the web but am not able to wrap my head around how to do it using sqldatasource. I am not able to connect how to trigger the query with the click of the button. I have this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SearchPDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IDBConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * from [tblPatron] WHERE LName = @LName" >
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLName" Name="LName" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" PropertyName="Text"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am trying to display the results in a grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SearchPDS" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

Also I wrote code behind for the onclick event for the button:

```
 Protected Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
 SearchPDS.SelectCommand = "Select * From tblPatron where LName = @LastName"
 SearchPDS.SelectParameters.Add("LastName", txtLName.Text)
 SearchPDS.DataBind()
GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: I am now just running the query on the click event and then tighing it to gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sqlsource code to

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SearchPDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * from [tblPatron]">  
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and running the query for the onclick event.

```
Protected Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = "SELECT * FROM tblPatron WHERE (LName Like '%" + txtLName.Text.ToString() + "%')"
    strSearch = strSearch + "AND (FNAME Like '%" + txtFName.Text.ToString() + "%')"
    SearchPDS.SelectCommand = strSearch
    GridSearchResults.Visible = True
End Sub
```

This seems to be working fine. Is there any sleek way of doing the same job?
Thanks
~ Nita